# OK to put board on ESD bag?

Tags: esd

I keep PCBA's in an ESD bag.  When I want to use them, I put them on the bag to avoid crushing any components on the bottom side.  Is this any better or worse than a table?

Comment: If you truly have a mechanical sensitivity, you probably want [*static-dissipative foam* (usually colored pink)](http://www.uline.com/BL_8000/Uline-Anti-Static-Foam), rather than *static-shielding film* (which ESD bags are made from)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt that components that won't get crushed when placed on the bag will get crushed when placed on a table. From the component crushing perspective, either one will be fine.

Presumably you're worried about the ESD bag shorting out components on the underside. This is likely not an issue, you can get more information from a [related question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/5990/15805).